# wants to change the color of actionbar in different activity

Tags: android

I m having a three activity and in all three activity ,by default the color of action bar is blue but here I want to change the color of action bar different in different activity what should I do.

Comment: Time to switch to Toolbar, it is much more flexible.

Comment: but it does not work with scrollview  it produce an error

Comment: can you upload the error log with scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You can do something programmatically like this in each Acivity

```
mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED));
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: @user8469159 you can change the color code in each Activity as you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this in after setContent in your on create for every Activity

```
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable();
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //if you are using v7 version then you should do this
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    colorDrawable.setColor(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.you_color));
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

if you are using fragments then you also need to add this

```
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: bro I try this but its not working...it crash my app and produce the error in  actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

Comment: you can try getSupportActionBar(); in place of getActionBar() see the updated answer @himanshu